# Need help understanding while-loops and what it is doing

Tags: python, loops

I am learning Python, and currently I am learning about sentinel loops. I have this piece of code that I need help understanding. What exactly is the while-loop doing? I did some research and I know it is looping through the if-statement (correct me if I am wrong); but is it looping through a specific equation until the user stops inputting their integers? Thank you in advanced.

(Please no hate comments I am still learning as a developer. & this is my first post Thanks)

```
even = 0  odd = 0

string_value = input("Please enter an int. value: ")

while string_value !="":
    int_value = int(string_value)
    if int_value % 2 == 0:
        even += 1
    else:
        odd += 1
    string_value = input("Please enter an int. value: ")

if even + odd == 0:
    print("No values were found. Try again...") else:
    print("Number of evens is: ", str(even)+".")
    print("Number of odd is: ", str(odd)+".")
```

---Updated Code:

```
def main():
    print("Process a series of ints enter at console \n")

    count_even = 0
    count_odd = 0

    num_str = input("Please enter an int. value or press <Enter> to stop: ")

    #Process with loop
    while num_str !="":
        num_int = int(num_str)
        if num_int % 2 == 0:
            count_even += 1
        else:
            count_odd += 1
        num_str = input("Please enter an int. value: ")

    if count_even + count_odd == 0:
        print("No values were found. Try again...")
    else:
        print("Number of evens is: ", str(count_even)+".")
        print("Number of odd is: ", str(count_odd)+".")



main()
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn about the rules of the site as well as [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: it will loop over as long as the input is not an empty string. (so basically a user will just press enter without inputing anything, also theoretically it is possible to enter a string that cannot be converted to an integer which will cause an error which will "stop" the loop as well as the whole program)

Comment: Apologies if my question did not meet the standards  and guidelines.

Comment: as for the while loop: it will loop over the block of code under it while the condition is met hence its name or if there is an error (which again will stop the whole program) or a `break` statement inserted somewhere it will stop then as well

Comment: @Matiiss It looks like the code is looping over and over the "Please enter..." portion and does not end. So what I am understanding is, if I put a break somewhere in the code, the loop will stop?

Comment: @PythonChic now break does break out of the loop but this loop will also end if there is nothing inputed and the input is submitted (enter key is pressed)

Comment: @Matiiss I've attached an updated code, but you've mentioned a break. Do you think in this situation it is helpful to have it?

Comment: @PythonChic first of there seems to be no point of making the whole thing a function (that seems very java like), and no in this particular case there is really no point for a break statement since the loop will break if the condition is not met (in this case it is if the input is an empty string). however here it would be useful to apply `try except` statements to catch errors such as user not inputing a whole number but don't try to wrap Your head around those yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing the while loop does is check if the user input is empty`while string_value !=""`, if it is not empty than it will start the loop. The `!=` means not equals and the `""` is empty so not equals empty. Next it sets the variable `int_value` as the integer of the user input(will error if user inputs anything other than whole number). Next it checks if the variable `int_value` % 2(remainder of division by 2) is 0, so pretty much it checks if the number is divisible by 2, if it is divisible by two it will add 1 to the `even` variable. Otherwise it will add 1 to the `odd` variable

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was looking for was an explanation. I know the code is not functionable and has potential errors but I needed someone to explain the loop to me as I am new to it.

Answer (score 0):

It will be very helpful if you go through python doc https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

```
even = 0  odd = 0
```

The above line `even` and `odd` are variables keeping count of even number and odd number.

```
string_value = input("Please enter an int. value: ")
```

The above line prompt the user to input an integer

```
while string_value !="":
    int_value = int(string_value)
    if int_value % 2 == 0:
        even += 1
    else:
        odd += 1
    string_value = input("Please enter an int. value: ")
```

The above while loop check firstly, if the input is not empty, `int()` Return an integer object constructed from a number or string `x`, or return 0 if no arguments are given https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int. The if statement takes the modulus of the integer value, and then increases the counter for either odd or even.

Finally, the count of odd and even are printed.

Comment: Hi and thank you for that. I feel confident about what is exactly going on in the code

Comment: It's a gradual process. Just try and check out some online resources

Answer (score -1):

the input() function waits until the user enters a string so unless the user enters an empty string the while loop will keep asking the user for strings in this line:
`string_value = input("Please enter an int. value: ")`
and check if its an empty string in this line:
`while string_value !="":`

Comment: I understand, I ran the code and you are right. It keeps asking the user to enter in a value but keeps looping and looping, and does not end.

Comment: @PythonChic look at the comments under Your question

Comment: try replacing the while statement to ```while string value:``` instead of ```!=''```

Comment: @Egjlmn1 It still is looping, no ending